# Making persistent USB with minimal OS on os x

Tags: osx, live-usb, uefi, bootable, small-distribution

I am looking to turn a 8Gb USB into a bootable drive with a minimal OS. All I want is an OS that will allow me to use vim, nothing else (no internet/any other services). I basically want to turn a USB into a digital typewriter.

I was able to make a bootable semi persistent Ubuntu USB using syslinux and uNetBootin on my mac. However, Ubuntu seems too bloated.

What would be a good OS for my needs? Also, could I make a persistent bootable USB with it?

Thanks :)

Comment: There are several small Linux distributions; you might pick one of them (I don't have any particular recommendation).

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you can always download a [Gentoo minimal install ISO image](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/) to [copy onto a USB key](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LiveUSB/Guide). It contains everything to access the network anyway. If you fancy some exploration you can still trim it down to disable or remove networking (i.e. `emerge openrc` *without* `netifrc` and `newnet` USE flags) but you'll have to [rebuild an entire system](http://www.anticore.org/ratgentoo/index.php?page=002).

Answer (score 0):

Can anything be smaller than [damn small linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) at 50Mbytes. It has vim and can persist data if you add a partition to your usb key.